# how to use keychainwrapper in iPhone device

Tags: ios, keychainitemwrapper

when i use this in simulator it is working, but when i run it in iPhone device does not work.

why this happen, how to do this?

```
- (void) RememberUserAccount:(NSString *) userName password:(NSString *) password {
//NSString *uuid = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
NSString *identifierForVendor = [[UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor UUIDString];
KeychainItemWrapper *keyWrapper=[[KeychainItemWrapper alloc]initWithIdentifier:identifierForVendor accessGroup:@"hello.lt"];
[keyWrapper setObject:userName forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
[keyWrapper setObject:password forKey:(id)kSecValueData];
```

}

this is the error:

```
erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Couldn't add the Keychain Item.'
```

thank!